# Salesforce Lightning and Classics showing different values

Tags: custom-field

I came across a weird issue. I have a percent field with precision up to 4 decimal points. We have some calculations which populate the value of that field. What I can see is after calculations if the value is low, its shown differently in classic and lightning. This popped up during a demo. I tested this on classic and gave a demo in lightning(which went bad). Ideally it should be same, if anyone can throw some light on this, would be helpful.

[image: Value of **APR** in classic]
[image: In Lightning]
[image: In Developer Console]

Steps to replicate:

1. Create (14,4) precison % field
2. Update it value to a lower number.

   Double d=Double.valueOf('6.2430516687936078306281214018618778468E-18');

   update new Opportunity(APR__C=d,id='00628000007Y078AAC');
3. Try to view it in Lightning,Classic and Workbench. Each view will show different value.

Comment: That is an extraordinarily small number that I would expect to produce 0.0000% in both cases. What do you get when you query the value using e.g. the Developer Console?

Comment: Updated pic to illustrate developer console value.

Comment: I was able to replicate this for both numbers and percents in my dev org.  Very strange indeed.  I'd suggest creating a case and trying to get it logged as a known issue.

Comment: I have raised a case #16169993. Lets see what follow up we get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce has identified it as a bug at their end and have provided a bug number **W-3906558** .  This is only reported by me so this cannot be marked as a known issue. For marking a bug as a known issue it should be brought to the notice by certain number of individuals. So No ETA as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chosen the database field to be 14,4 then to keep control of rounding you should use the Decimal type in your logic and invoke [setScale(scale, roundsingMode)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) at the end of your Apex logic with a scale of 4 and your rounding mode of choice. That way what is presented and what is persisted in the database are the same; that avoids later surprises when hidden digit values influence later logic. Setting the scale of a field affects it presentation: it does not automatically scale the value when it is stored in the database.

(Having said that your results are surprising and indicate that extreme values - 6.2 Quintillionths in your case - are not well handled by default by the platform.)

Comment: Seems to be a bug in SF's rounding algorithm. It havent rounded properly while storing in the DB

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Not a bug, more a design choice.